# ssh run command if we are on specific folder

Tags: ssh

I have this code on my .bashrc

```
 alias chdev='chown -R www-data:www-data ./*'
```

But as you can see this is very dangerous so I want to perform and if statement and run the command `chdev` only if we are on the folder `/var/www/projects/dev/user1/*/htdocs` or any subfolder inside htdocs

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
 alias chdev='[[ "$PWD" =~ /var/www/projects/dev/user1/.*/htdocs ]] && chown -R www-data:www-data ./*'
```